# How can i find an Id by Linq Query in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I have a table Named Product that has mapping with ProductCategory.I want to find an ProductCategoryId in product controller. How can i achieve this. I have applied linq query here but how can i use it to find productCategoryId.

```
var productCategoryId = (from ProductCategory in context.ProductCategories
                                             where (ProductCategory.ProductId==id)
                                           select ProductCategory);
```

Now I m trying to find out an Id from database which may contain in productCategoryId but it is not accessible here, Like,

```
var proCategoryId = _categoryService.GetProductCategoryById(productCategoryId);
```

how can i find achieve this.

Comment: Please clarify your question - it doesn't make sense at the moment.

Comment: I have a table Named Product that has mapping with ProductCategory.I want to find an ProductCategoryId in product controller. How can i achieve this. I have applied linq query here but how can i use it to find productCategoryId.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: Please post your complete code and please edit your question rather than adding a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var productCategoryId = (from ProductCategory in context.ProductCategories
                         where ProductCategory.ProductId==id
                         select ProductCategory.ProductCategoryId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: but i have a method in service layer which requires integer type parameter. than how can i pass integer value when i have in service layer when i have productCategoryId of type var. Like


_categoryService.GetProductCategoryById(productCategoryId);

Comment: var is an implicit type. In this case, var will be an int (assuming ProductCategoryId is an int). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) for more info.

Comment: no it isn't taking productCategoryId as a parameter. the red line shows that the best overload method match for "Commerce.Services.ICategoryService.GetProductCategoryId(int)" has some invalid arguments.

Comment: @AnuragMittal, show us the schema for the `ProductCategories` table, or just replace in Teppic's code the `.ProductCategoryId` with the actual name of the field in the `ProductCategories` table that stores the ProductCategoryID.

Comment: Yes I found the solution thnks @Teppic